# Getting Values Across Many Tables Including MAX and NULLs

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000, join

So I'l try and explain the DB setup

**tblEDS**

```
eID | eVal1     | eVal2
-------------------------------------
1   | Monday    | Joe
2   | Tuesday   | Bob
3   | Wednesday | Jan
4   | Thursday  | Pete
```

**tblPatient (I realise this isn't the best DB design around!)**

```
pID | pVal1     | pVal2 | pEDS
------------------------------
1   | Monday    | 123   | 1
2   | Tuesday   | 456   | 2
```

**tblPatientRecords**

```
pID | rID
------------
1   | 1
1   | 2
2   | 3
2   | 4
```

**tblRecords**

```
rID | rVal1 | rVal2
-------------------
1   | Ok    | Boy
2   | Well  | Man
3   | Dead  | Kid
4   | Dead  | Girl
```

What I need is a query to pull back all records in tblAlert regardless of whether it has a corresponding value in tblPatient or not. For each record that exists in tblPatient, I need the relevant maximum rID and relevant values given back i.e.

```
eID | eVal1     | eVal2 | pID  | pVal1   | pVal2 | rID  | rVal1  | rVal2     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | Monday    | Joe   | 1    | Monday  | 123   | 2    | Well   | Man
2   | Tuesday   | Bob   | 2    | Tuesday | 456   | 4    | Dead   | Girl
3   | Wednesday | Jan   | NULL | NULL    | NULL  | NULL | NULL   | NULL   
4   | Thursday  | Pete  | NULL | NULL    | NULL  | NULL | NULL   | NULL
```

There are a lot more columns for tblEDS, tblPatient and tblRecords but not shown here

Comment: look at doing an outer join :)

Comment: What are those 'Alive', 'Dead' etc. essentially? Are they *record types* or actual *records*? In other words, can there be duplicates of `rValue`?

Comment: Just values the user enters. There's loads of columns but I just added one for ease. There can be duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  a.eID,
  a.eValue,
  t.pID,
  t.pName,
  t.rID,
  t.rValue
FROM tblAlert a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      p.pID,
      p.pName,
      p.eID,
      r.rID,
      r.rValue
    FROM tblPatient p
      INNER JOIN (
        SELECT pID, MAX(rID) AS rID
        FROM tblPatientRecords
        GROUP BY pID
      ) pr ON p.pID = pr.pID
      INNER JOIN tblRecords r ON pr.rID = r.rID
  ) t ON a.eID = t.eID
```

Comment: No luck I'm afraid.

Column 'dbo.tblPatientRecords.pID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in an aggregate function and there is no GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Comma needed after t.rID, e.eID needs to be a.eID. Generally it's what I'm after, just need to work out how to add all the columns! Thanks.

Comment: Alright, alright, you got me. I confess: I wrote this off the top of my head and didn't even bother using SSMS for syntax check at least. Sorry. :)